# External API called in a route, and testing the route in node JS

Tags: node.js, express, get, postman

I have the below route created in my application which calls another API for data:

```
newsr.get('/news', async (req, res) => {
    var category = req.params.category;
    try {
        var url = 'http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=general' + '&apiKey=36f3e29b704f41339af8439dc1228334';

        const news_get = await axios.get(url)
        res.status(200).json().render('category', { articles: news_get.data.articles })
        // return res.status(200).json(news_get)
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
})
```

The problem is, when I call the get API http://localhost:8080/news. I do not get the response from the external API. Can you please suggest what to do?

Comment: what response do you get if you `console.log(news_get)`?

Comment: Apparently, I get none! I added console.log and got nothing in return on console.

Comment: I tried this with postman & the API is returning data... and to be honest I don't see anything incorrect with your request... try to create a demo js code and simply try to call it from there... share the results